# SEOs: mobile version using AJAX: how to be properly read by crawlers?

Tags: seo, search-engines, mobile, ajax

Before anything else, I'd like to emphasize that I've already read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26073/can-a-mobile-version-of-site-be-considered-duplication-by-google-if-the-page-is) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/does-having-a-mobile-version-of-a-website-improve-the-page-rank).

Here's what I can do:

First choice:

- create classical web version with all products in that page - `http://www.myweb.com`.
- create mobile web version with all products in the page and use jQuery Mobile to format all nicely but this may be long to (load + format), and may provide bad user experience  - `http://m.myweb.com`.

Second choice:

- create classical web version with all products in that page
- create mobile web version with almost nothing but a Web page showing *wait*, then download all products in the page using AJAX and use jQuery Mobile to format all nicely. Showing a *wait, loading* message gives far more time to do whatever I want and may provide *better* user experience  - `http://m.myweb.com`.

Question: if I choose the second solution, Google won't read anything on the mobile version (because all products will be downloaded in the page using AJAX), so it wont be properly read by crawlers. What / how shall I do?

Comment: But isn't google already reading your content at www.myweb.com and m.myweb.com is technically duplicate content?

Comment: @huzzah Well, if you search a bit around (on this site) you'll see that with proper tags in head, google "guesses" it's for mobile and doesn't consider it's duplicate.

Comment: @huzzah It's here => http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32517/url-for-separate-mobile-site

Comment: excellent.  I had derped on using rel=canonical but i didn't know about the Vary HTTP header and using rel=alternate.

Answer (score 1):

I would do **Choice (3):**

- make www.myweb.com work well on a mobile device using adaptive/responsive design using [@media queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=@media%20queries) so that www.myweb.com/products (or whatever) works flawlessly on mobile.
- **not** use m.myweb.com at all
- **not** use ajax at all. Show 10 or 20 products on the first page with pagination. Include a link 'Show all products' for those who wish the massive page (like Google)

Splitting off into two domains I would think the rank gets diluted a bit. I also think it is harder to maintain. In this day and age we don't really need to develop on separate domains any more. It would probably best place development hours in making a native phone app (iphone or android) if you really want to get fancy on the mobile.

I outline reasons why going with two domains domains in the same question you referenced in the comments: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/32728/17132

Comment: **`(*.*)`** not use m.myweb.com at all? Even google suggests to use the prefix `m.` for mobile... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY9h3G8Lv4k

Comment: @OlivierPons Yes that's right, don't use m dot. In the video Matt suggested m dot which is fine. Mine is also a suggestion. Neither is a wrong way to go. I'd still choose the non m dot separation for mobile. Also notice only one time Mr. Cutts talks about duplicate content in the video & says something like 'You shouldn't have duplicate content issues but if you do contact us'. My suggestion is to make a website that does not need ANY user agent sniffing & redirection nonsense. Here's a perfect example of a site which works on any modern device & browser: http://css-tricks.com/